# How to correctly use the Google Maps Geocoding endpoint? It's not returning correctly place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API Geocoding to convert address to latitude/longitude, but it's not returning the correct values.

For example, with this address:
15994 US Hwy 431, Headland, AL 36345

Using this endpoint:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=15994+US+Hwy+431,+Headland,+AL+36345&key=(apikey)

The Google Maps Geocoding API is returning (Which is not correct):

"location": {
"lat": 32.8365989,
"lng": -84.8436105
},

[image]

However, if I search for that address in the google maps application it's pointing the correct address (it's changing automatically in the search bar to 15994 US-431 after pressing enter):

[image]

After testing a while, I discovered that if I change "Hwy" for "Highway" it does return the correct address. Is there any way to fix this?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=15994+US+Highway+431,+Headland,+AL+36345&key=(apikey)

Is there any way to make it understand abbreviations? Like Hwy for example

Comment: It also works if you remove the "Hwy" (discovered using the Places autocomplete service): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=15994+US+431,+Headland,+AL+36345&key=(apiKey)

Comment: A reverse geocoding of the coords from your "working" example returns *15994 US-431, Headland, AL 36345, USA*. If you believe there is a data issue you should file a bug in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188871&s=created_time:desc).